# Autolayout : Align two button side by side and move to right side when there is no image

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have two buttons with added image on two button.

I need to check programatically and remove button the other button will move right side.

I know one way to do it.

Add width constraint and set it to zero programatically but i dont want to do it.

I want to do it according to image. if image is not placed on button it width will be zero and other button will move right side.

is it possible?

I am using IB.

My current constraint is :

[My Constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J64PJ.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using two different buttons inside [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) will be very easy & effective:

[image: 2 Diffrent buttons inside UIStackview]
[image: 1st button is hide]

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting iOS 9 and above, I'd recommend using a [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) for that. Then, you can just set the button's visibility to `hidden` and it should move as you want.